# python 2.5: how to convert float to hex?

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

I want to convert a float (the output of `time.time()`) in hex using python 2.4/2.5.

I found tons of examples that convert hex to float, but I cannot find anything that allows me to do what the `float.hex()` of python >= 2.6 does.

Comment: It would help if you said WHY you want to do that e.g. what is going to consume the hex string?

Comment: I need it to create a unique identifier (together with other stuff). If you want to know why that, the answer is: it's not my choice.

Comment: If you don't need to be able to recover the time from the unique id, and you just want different times to yield different numbers, try hash(time.time()) to get an integer and hex(hash(time.time())) to get a string in '0xBLAHBLAH' form.

Comment: @Russell Borogove: aarrgghh it is possible for `hash(x) == hash(y) and x != y` to evaluate to `True` ... he wants it to be **UNIQUE**

Comment: If you want a unique identifier, just use the uuid module (http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html) - it was made for that reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be done portably in Python before version 2.6; it needs the information in sys.float_info, which is new in Python 2.6.

If you want to do it non-portably, i.e. for your particular platform, you would need to look at the `float.h` file for the C compiler that was used to produce your 2.4/5 Python, or at the sys.float_info returned by a 2.6 or 2.7 implementation on your platform (and trust that it applies to your 2.4/5 Python). Then you would need to look at the `float_hex` function in the Python source (Objects/floatobject.c) and translate that to Python and test it (against a 2.6/7 Python, perhaps).

This seems like a lot of work, for what? What is your goal? What do you want to do that can't be achieved with `repr(your_float)`?

**Edit**: need for a unique identifier

Note that time.time() is not very precise:

"""
time.time() 
Return the time as a floating point number expressed in seconds since the epoch, in UTC. Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.
"""

Allowing for up to a billionth of a second resolution:

```
>>> hex(int(time.time() * 1000000000))
'0x11ef11c41cf98b00L'
>>>
```

Is that good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the C version of the code, I don't have time to port it right now, but maybe someone else can.

```
float_hex(PyObject *v)
{
    double x, m;
    int e, shift, i, si, esign;
    /* Space for 1+(TOHEX_NBITS-1)/4 digits, a decimal point, and the
       trailing NUL byte. */
    char s[(TOHEX_NBITS-1)/4+3];

    CONVERT_TO_DOUBLE(v, x);

    if (Py_IS_NAN(x) || Py_IS_INFINITY(x))
        return float_str((PyFloatObject *)v);

    if (x == 0.0) {
        if (copysign(1.0, x) == -1.0)
            return PyString_FromString("-0x0.0p+0");
        else
            return PyString_FromString("0x0.0p+0");
    }

    m = frexp(fabs(x), &e);
    shift = 1 - MAX(DBL_MIN_EXP - e, 0);
    m = ldexp(m, shift);
    e -= shift;

    si = 0;
    s[si] = char_from_hex((int)m);
    si++;
    m -= (int)m;
    s[si] = '.';
    si++;
    for (i=0; i < (TOHEX_NBITS-1)/4; i++) {
        m *= 16.0;
        s[si] = char_from_hex((int)m);
        si++;
        m -= (int)m;
    }
    s[si] = '\0';

    if (e < 0) {
        esign = (int)'-';
        e = -e;
    }
    else
        esign = (int)'+';

    if (x < 0.0)
        return PyString_FromFormat("-0x%sp%c%d", s, esign, e);
    else
        return PyString_FromFormat("0x%sp%c%d", s, esign, e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it can be done in a portable way, it's just maths. Here's how (inclusing tests proving it works).

```
from __future__ import division

MAXHEXADECIMALS = 10

def float2hex(f):
    w = f // 1
    d = f % 1

    # Do the whole:
    if w == 0:
        result = '0'
    else:
        result = ''
    while w:
        w, r = divmod(w, 16)
        r = int(r)
        if r > 9:
            r = chr(r+55)
        else:
            r = str(r)
        result =  r + result

    # And now the part:
    if d == 0:
        return result

    result += '.'
    count = 0
    while d:
        d = d * 16
        w, d = divmod(d, 1)
        w = int(w)
        if w > 9:
            w = chr(w+55)
        else:
            w = str(w)
        result +=  w
        count += 1
        if count > MAXHEXADECIMALS:
            break

    return result


import unittest
class Float2HexTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ints(self):
        assert float2hex(0x25) == '25'
        assert float2hex(0xFE) == 'FE'
        assert float2hex(0x00) == '0'
        assert float2hex(0x01) == '1'
        assert float2hex(0x14E7F400A5) == '14E7F400A5'

    def test_floats(self):
        assert float2hex(1/2) == '0.8'
        assert float2hex(1/13) == '0.13B13B13B13'
        assert float2hex(1034.03125) == '40A.08'

suite = unittest.makeSuite(Float2HexTest)
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)
```

Yeah, that's pretty pointless. :-)
Of course, the correct answer in this case is to not convert a float to hex, but to use an INTEGER representation of time and convert that to a hex string. But still, it can be done. :)