# Decoding and formatting for newbies in Python

Tags: python

I am just trying to do some quick debugging of some Python script, but I am struggeling
a bit as I am a complete newbie with the syntax. I get some data in via the network, that is assigned as you can see in the following:

```
a = self.block.decode('hex')[95:63:-1]
b = self.midstate.decode('hex')[::-1]
payload = a + b 
print("Data Received {} \n", payload)
```

I would be interested in two things:

1. How many bytes/bit are hold in `payload`? I tried `payload__len()` but that did not work
2. I would like to output the `payload` value in 32 bit hex word, anyone knows how this can be done with Python?

Answer (score 1):

for 1:

in python length is a seperate from the object. so,
 `len(payload)` gives you the length of payload, as long as payload is an object that can have length.

example:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4]
>>> len(lst)
4
```

for 2:

[python 2.5: how to convert float to hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432491/python-2-5-how-to-convert-float-to-hex)

example for you:

```
>>> hex(800)
'0x320'
>>> hex(123456789)
'0x75bcd15'
```